# Getting cannot read properties of undefined from useSate in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting in React. In an application I have a form that I created to view details of a customer. I consume an API that has several clients and in this form I load detailed information (I pass an id and call find). I have rows to feed a table and employee to fill the form

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
const [employee, setEmployee] = useState<Employee>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    new EmployeeService()
      .findAll()
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      })
      .then((res) => setRows(res));
  }, []);

const employeeView = async (id: string) => {    
    await new EmployeeService()
      .find(id)
      .then((res) => {        
        return res.data;        
      })
      .then((res) => setEmployee(res));        
   
  };
<Dialog fullScreen open={openDialog} onClose={close}>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              Employee
            </DialogContentText>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="name"              
              value={employee.name}
            />
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              margin="dense"
              id="factory"              
              value={employee.factoryName}
            />          
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={setDialog}>Close</Button>
          </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

But since employee is only populated after clicking a button to view the employee details, it is returning the error in the browser console “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading name)”

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Yes and I didn't understand how to avoid it

Comment: value={employee.name} Try change to value={employee?.name}

Comment: You also could try Suspense

Comment: `employee` is undefined, which the error clearly shows. Since you initialize employee to `[]`, empty array, and `[].name` doesn't error, that means that your employee is undefined after you retrieve it from the API. That means `res.data` is undefined. Get in the habit of using `console.log` to debug your code and check what variables are.

Comment: Your question is confusing because your code doesn't use `employeeView`. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question (don't comment) to add appropriate debugging details.

Comment: I've hidden the employeeView call, as I've implied that there is a button that is calling it (and it's working). The code runs if I remove the line that has value={employee.name} and value={employee.factory}

Comment: @antokhio I've tried that option too and it didn't work.

Comment: <Employee>([]) should be ({})

Comment: type Employee = {… ; name?: string}

Comment: @antokhio The error persists. And before you believe it is some error in the API. I can give console.log(employee) and return the information.

Comment: Check the spelling and that response in not wrapped in some ‘data’ like data data

Comment: @antokhio I gave console.log and there is a return only with res.data and not with res.data.data (returns undefined)

Comment: You can try name={employee ? employee.name : ‘’}

Comment: @antokhio It only works when I do  name={employee ? ' ' : employee.name }, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @antokhio I achieved! I went for a walk and saw that I didn't make the correct adjustments. Thank you very much